# Why does this LINQ statement return null and not a IEnumerable with count=0

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a method that is supposed to do the following :
- Retrieve a list of objects from an webservice (works as expected)
- Return a subset of those objects based on a couple of criterias(doesn´t work)

```
    private List<AliveDTO> getDeads()
    {
        List<AliveDTO> DTOs = APIRequests.Instance.GetAliveDTOs();

        var deads = DTOs.Where(x =>
            x.watchWindowStartTime.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0 ||
            x.watchWindowEndTime.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) > 0 && 
            DateTime.Now > x.timeReceived.AddMinutes((double)x.NextAliveWithinMinutes));
        List<AliveDTO> deadInList = deads as List<AliveDTO>;
        return deadInList;
    }
```

I expected to the variable deads to be an IEnumerable with count=0 if no entities in the list matched the criterias, however i get a null value instead.

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: because `as List<AliveDTO>` where `deads` is not `List<AliveDTO>` (not derived from it)

Comment: solution is to use `deads.ToList()`

Comment: "I expected to the variable deads to be an IEnumerable with count=0" - and it is. It's just not a `List<AliveDTO>`. If you'd use a cast instead of the `as` operator, you'd have seen the cast fail.

Comment: @Selvin , If deeds is null, how could deeds.ToList() works?

Comment: It cannot be null (as `Where(...)` extension doesn't return null) ... what could return null is `DTOs?.Where(...)` ... then obviously you could use `deeds?.ToList()`

Comment: Thank you. Using ToList() did indeed fix my problem :)

Comment: *Using ToList() did indeed fix my problem* this one ... but  ... GetAliveDTOs seems to returns whole data from DB ... maybe you should postopne materialization after adding this condisions ... so the condisions would be checked "on database"

Comment: To be fair, we dont really know what GetAliveDtos does. It might as well be pulling objects from a service, cache...

Comment: The documentation on the [as operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as) may be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that 'deads' would not be a List. It would be an *IEnumerable*. Adding the .ToList() Linq command will make 'deads' a type of List. I would also refactor it slightly, since you are creating a second List below deads. :)

```
private List<AliveDTO> getDeads()
{
    List<AliveDTO> DTOs = APIRequests.Instance.GetAliveDTOs();

    return DTOs.Where(x =>
        x.watchWindowStartTime.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0 ||
        x.watchWindowEndTime.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) > 0 && 
        DateTime.Now > x.timeReceived.AddMinutes((double)x.NextAliveWithinMinutes)).ToList();
}
```